# Why does this error message keep popping up even though I clearly referenced two different tables?

Tags: sql, database

When I execute my code, I keep receiving this error message:

Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'AccountNo'.

I clearly referenced the AccountNo columns from the InvoiceLineItems and GLAccounts tables yet it tells me that the AccountNo is still an ambiguous name in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT VendorName, VendorState, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal, AccountNo,
       InvoicelineItemDescription, AccountDescription
FROM   Vendors JOIN Invoices
    ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
JOIN InvoiceLineItems
    ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
JOIN GLAccounts
    ON InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo = GLAccounts.AccountNo
WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal > 0
ORDER BY VendorName;
```

Comment: You also need to qualify `AccountNo` in the select clause (not just the from clause).

Comment: You don't even have a `from` clause so this statement is invalid.

Comment: Qualify all your column names!

Comment: I should have clarified that these are just part of the sections of the entire code that is affected. Would it help if I post the entire code to this post?

Comment: I added in the rest of the codes for clarification. Hopefully the moderators won't be giving me hell over this.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have the same column names in multiple tables.

You are selecting `AccountNo` in your column list and the column exists in `GLAccounts` and `InvoiceLineItems`. The databases is saying to you "I don't know which one of those two columns you want, without you specifying the *table* it's ambiguous".

This is why you should always use *meaningful aliases* and always qualify your columns with the appropriate alias, it means there's no ambiguity, you are less likely to make a mistake and reading the query is a lot easier.

```
select 
    v.VendorName, 
    v.VendorState, 
    i.InvoiceNumber, 
    i.InvoiceTotal, 
    g.AccountNo, 
    li.InvoicelineItemDescription, 
    g.AccountDescription
from Vendors v
join Invoices i on v.VendorID = i.VendorID
join InvoiceLineItems li on li.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
join GLAccounts g on g.AccountNo = li.AccountNo
where i.InvoiceTotal - i.PaymentTotal - i.CreditTotal > 0
order by v.VendorName;
```

I guessed at which aliases to use in the above but you get the idea; of course, had you qualified each column with the specific table to remove ambiguity, no guessing would be required.

Comment: I see, so I could also pair the columns with their respective table names in the SELECT statements to clarify from which tables I want to use the column names.

Comment: What I don't understand was that it was fine reading the columns from the other tables. Why would it all of a sudden have issues determining the tables for the AccountNo columns?

Comment: You do not have the problem when the *other table(s)* you mention do not have columns with the same name.  But, if you always alias your tables and always reference columns as `table_alias.column_name` then you **never** have this problem. Good Practice: assign an alias for each table then always use that alias for reference. You may occasionally have to handle alias collision, for example a self join or two tables with similar names, but you can always differentiate with additional number of letter.

Comment: *so I could also pair the columns with their respective table names*  - yes, tablename.columnname is fine, but SQL provides for the use of aliases in order to make life easier and code more readable, a single letter to prefix your columns is easier than ThisReallyLongTableName.ColumnName repeated many times. You only *technically* require to add the table/alias name for clashing column names - as in your case - SQL can work out which table the column is in otherwise; generally it's good practice to alias everything - when someone else looks at your code they don't have to guess.